# Two displays - Menu Bar disappears in fullscreen

Tags: macos, display

I have two displays: My MacBook Pro and and external display (primary screen). When watching a YouTube video in fullscreen mode, the Menu Bar on the external screen disappears. The Menu Bar contains the clock, which I want to remain visible.

How can I prevent the Menu Bar from disappearing while in full-screen mode?

Comment: What browser are you using? I get different results in Firefox and Safari, and also different results depending on whether Firefox is already in fullscreen mode or not.

Answer (score 3):

When using full-screen the application will take over the entire screen space.  Unfortunately there doesn’t seem to be a way to make it always display.  You should, however, be able to move your cursor to the top of the screen and make the menu bar appear that way.

Comment: On a multi-monitor system, the menu bar typically stays on the "other" monitor, when an app is full-screened on one monitor. (Though I suspect that this might be affected by System settings -> Mission Control -> Monitors have separate spaces)